# MutableLiveData observe is never triggered

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I have a two fragments that need to share an integer for the score in a very simple game.

In the first fragment (imagine a game view) I have:

```
    val currentScore: Int = viewModel.score.value ?: 0
    viewModel.score.postValue(currentScore + 1)
```

I have confirmed with the debugger that the above code is run when the player scores a point.

in the second fragment (imagine it is a scoreboard) I have:

```
  override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
      viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GameViewModel::class.java)
      //the TextView we want to show the integer score
      val scoreText = gameScoreLayout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.scoreValue)

      //registering an observer for changes to the score
      viewModel.score.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
          @Override fun onChange(score: Int){
              scoreText.scoreValue.text = score.toString()
          }
      })
  }
```

I have confirmed with the debugger that the onChange method is never being called.

my ViewModel is very simple:

```
class GameViewModel : ViewModel() {
  var score = MutableLiveData<Int>()
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `viewLifecycleOwner` here?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman see https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getViewLifecycleOwner%28%29  "In most cases, this mirrors the lifecycle of the Fragment itself, but in cases of detached Fragments, the lifecycle of the Fragment can be considerably longer than the lifecycle of the View itself."

Comment: A tangent, but is `@Override fun` valid Kotlin code?

Comment: Here you are passing the lifecycleowner as fragment but you need to pas the activity -
Replace       viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GameViewModel::class.java)
with 
      viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(GameViewModel::class.java)

Comment: @stkent more than just a tangent. that ended up being the root problem. Yes it is valid Kotlin code, No it doesn't do what you'd expect.

Comment: Woah, I didn't see that coming!

Answer (score 3):

When you use `ViewModelProviders.of(this)`, you are using the individual Fragment's `ViewModelStore` which has its own set of ViewModels. Therefore your second Fragment doesn't have the same instance of the ViewModel as your first Fragment.

If you want to share ViewModels between Fragments, you need to [follow the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) and use a ViewModel scoped to the Activity or parent Fragment that both can access:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(GameViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: This really looked like it would be the answer, but I have corrected both fragments to use their parent activity to get the view model and the observe method is still not getting called. I forgot to mention that the postValue() is being called in an onTouchEvent() not sure if that is relevant. Not sure if i should re-ask as a separate question.

Comment: If you print the ViewModel variable out (i.e., `Log.d("Testing", viewModel)`), are they the exact same ViewModel object? I suspect you also have a problem with your `currentScore`, which should be `val currentScore: Int get() = viewModel.score.value ?: 0` if you want it to be recomputed each time (you could also just use `MutableLiveData(0)` and then just use `score.data` to get the value instead of having a separate variable).

Comment: `ViewModelProviders` is deprecated use `ViewModelProvider`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share ViewModel between two different fragments then you have to initiate `ViewModel` with activity instance like this inside both your game view fragment and scoreboard fragment.

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
  viewModel = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this)[GameViewModel::class.java]
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")

  //the TextView we want to show the integer score
  val scoreText = gameScoreLayout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.scoreValue)

  //registering an observer for changes to the score
  viewModel.score.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
      @Override fun onChange(score: Int){
          scoreText.scoreValue.text = score.toString()
      }
  })  
}
```

You can check out the official documentation regarding this [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have addressed one problem, but the main problem was that

```
viewModel.score.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
      @Override fun onChange(score: Int){
          scoreText.scoreValue.text = score.toString()
      }
  })
```

DOES NOT create a subclass of Observer and override the onChange(). The solution that ended up working was:

```
    class ScoreObserver: Observer<Int> {
        override fun onChanged(score: Int?) {
            scoreText.scoreValue.text = score.toString()
            Log.d("viewModel", "in ScoreObserver score: " + score.toString())
        }
    }
    viewModel.score.observe(requireActivity(), ScoreObserver())
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot observe the MutableLiveData because it was never initialized.

Thus the **ViewModel** class needs a small change ...

```
class GameViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var score = MutableLiveData<Int>()

    init {
        score.value = 0 //lets assume it as default value
    }
}
```

This worked for me.
Comment down if you still face any problems.